# В чем разница между функциональными и скриптовыми языками?

Tags: терминология

Насколько я понимаю в функциональных языках ты сам пишешь инструкции , а в скриптовых  ты используешь уже готовые сценарии(команды) ?

Comment: Программа на чистом функциональном языке это не сценарий (script), а скорее формула, в которую подставляются входные данные, и таким образом вычисляются выходные.

Answer (score 6):

Вы путаете тёплое с мягким.

Есть 3 парадигмы программирования и есть языки, которые поддерживают ту или иную парадигму:

- процедурное программирование (pascal, c, ...)
- объектно-ориентированное программирование (java, c++, ...)
- функциональное программирование (haskell, scala, ...)

Есть 2 типа трансляции программы - компиляция и интерпретация, скриптовые языки программирования - это те, которые используют интерпретацию. И это никак не влияет на поддерживаемую парадигму программирования.

Comment: Только три? А куда делась парадигма логического программирования (Prolog)?  Процедурое программирование же, насколько я знаю, это лишь вариант императивной парадигмы.

Comment: Соглашусь, их гораздо больше, в ответе были приведены эти 3 наиболее популярные для примера, чтобы указать на абсурдность вопроса.